# How to assign a sender name in SMSLib?

Tags: java, sms, gateway, smslib

I'm using **SMSLib** in my java application to *send messages*, I make that using a **usb modem** as a *gateway* and send the messages to any phone throw it, the point here that when i receive the message it displays the sender as the sim number(the sim that exists in the usb modem).
The thing i want to do is to assign a name instead of the sim number so the recipient will see that name not the *usb modem sim number*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases sender name is overridden by the Service Provider to their identification 'SIM number'.

By the Library it provides two locations to set sender information.

**On gateway level**

```
SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com4",
                "COM4", 57600, "Huawei", "E160");
gateway.setFrom("chandpriyankara");
```

**On Message level**

*SMS*

```
OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage("+94123456789",
                "SMS test: sample message from StackOverflow");
msg.setFrom("chandpriyankara");
```

I couldn't set a customer sender for SMS from either of my tested SMS providers[GSM Providers]. But this should work for buld SMS gateways. You have to discuss this with your service provider.

*WAP*

```
OutboundWapSIMessage wapMsg = new OutboundWapSIMessage("+94123456789",
                new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/"),
                "WAP test: sample message from StackOverflow!");
wapMsg.setFrom("chandpriyankara");
```

For WAP messages, some of GSM providers set my custom sender details, but not all.

Comment: well, this solution works for some purposes for me, but on the other side i want that name to appear on the phone itself. any ideas ?

Comment: As my experience it works for WAP messages but not SMS since the operator overrides the setFrom by sender mobile number. So it depends on the service provider's configurations.

Answer (score 1):

You can put sender information to your message instance before sending.

```
message.setFrom("your sender information");
```

Additionally it may depend on your GSM provider.

Comment: well, this solution works for some purposes for me, but on the other side i want that name to appear on the phone itself. any ideas ?